# Possible to build a scenario outline with multiple examples with KIF?

Tags: ios, objective-c, integration-testing, kif-framework, kif

I'm using KIF for integration/acceptance testing in my iOS app and I have an example that needs to run through ~50 static table rows expecting specific content on the view pushed onto the stack.

If I was in the Cucumber/Rspec world I would write a Scenario Outline similar to Cucumber's example:

```
Scenario Outline: eating
  Given there are <start> cucumbers
  When I eat <eat> cucumbers
  Then I should have <left> cucumbers

 Examples:
   | start | eat | left |
   |  12   |  5  |  7   |
   |  20   |  5  |  15  |
```

Where the scenario would run for each example and record individual pass/failures. Is there an easy way recreate this with KIF (2.0)? I could almost recreate it by looping through each 'example' and reporting a failure if one execution of the loop fails, but I'm concerned that would only appear as one failure when in reality multiple examples were tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized after asking the question that what I'd really need to use to achieve this is SenTestingKit (not necessarily KIF). I used a variation on the solution from http://briancoyner.github.io/blog/2011/09/12/ocunit-parameterized-test-case/ to run multiple tests using the same test method and different values each run.

I added a `description` method to my SenTestCase subclass, which provides support for Xcode 5's test navigator. With one test method, you can see a run of the test for each parameter set. By modifying the `description` method you can uniquely name each run. The approach is similar to the blog post I linked to but I'll provide my implementation here:

WMScenarioOutline.h

```
#import <KIF/KIF.h>

@interface WMScenarioOutline : SenTestCase

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *example;

- (id)initWithInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation example:(NSDictionary *)example;

@end
```

WMScenarioOutline.m

```
#import "WMScenarioOutline.h"

@implementation WMScenarioOutline

+ (id)defaultTestSuite
{
    SenTestSuite *testSuite = [[SenTestSuite alloc] initWithName:NSStringFromClass(self)];
    [self addTestCaseWithExample:@{@"name" : @"Foo", @"value" : @0} toTestSuite:testSuite];
    [self addTestCaseWithExample:@{@"name" : @"Bar", @"value" : @1} toTestSuite:testSuite];

    return testSuite;
}

+ (void)addTestCaseWithExample:(NSDictionary *)example toTestSuite:(SenTestSuite *)suite
{
    NSArray *testInvocations = [self testInvocations];
    for (NSInvocation *testInvocation in testInvocations) {
        SenTestCase *testCase = [[WMScenarioOutline alloc] initWithInvocation:testInvocation example:example];
        [suite addTest:testCase];
    }
}

- (id)initWithInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation example:(NSDictionary *)example
{
    self = [super initWithInvocation:anInvocation];
    if (self) {
        _example = example;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)testScenarioOutline
{
    [tester runBlock:^KIFTestStepResult(NSError *__autoreleasing *error) {
        NSLog(@"Testing example: %@", self.example);
        return [self.example[@"value"] intValue] == 0 ? KIFTestStepResultSuccess : KIFTestStepResultFailure;
    }];
}

- (NSString *)description
{
    NSInvocation *invocation = [self invocation];

    NSString *name = NSStringFromSelector(invocation.selector);
    if ([name hasPrefix:@"test"]) {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-[%@ %@%@]", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(invocation.selector), self.example[@"name"]];
    }
    else {
        return [super description];
    }
}

@end
```

[image: Unique runs of the same test method with different parameters]

There is plenty of room here for improvement but this is a good place to start.